# How to extract depth map from .heif image created with iphone X using imagemagick

Tags: iphone, imagemagick, heic

i created an image with my own iPhone app. The image is in .heif format and it contains the depth map. (i know this because the [Photos](https://www.apple.com/macos/photos/) app recognizes it)
I now downloaded and installed [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/index.php). 
and ran the following command:

```
magick identify -verbose orginal.HEIC
```

This shows me only three channels (Channel 0, Channel 1, Channel 2). I guess these are the rgb colors of the image.

How can I access the depth data of this image?

Comment: Related off-site content: https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=34813 (I assume OP made post #11)

Answer (score 9):

I don’t know about using ImageMagick itself, but ImageMagick relies on [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif), and if that’s installed, e.g., with `brew install libheif`, then the [`heif-convert`](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/blob/master/examples/heif_convert.cc) example program will do this with the `--with-aux` option:

```
# heif-convert --with-aux IMG_0123.HEIC blah.jpg
File contains 1 images
Written to blah.jpg
Depth image written to blah-depth.jpg
```

Note that older versions of heif-convert did not have options and wrote out those extra files by default.

Comment: This no longer seems to work. For me at least with the latest version of `heif-convert` I get just a jpg from an image that I know has depth information (I have transferred it back to my iphone and was still able to toggle portrait mode).

Comment: @JohnCH Post updated, does the updated answer work for you? I tried a newer photo and actually got an image called `urn:com:apple:photo:2020:aux:hdrgainmap.jpg`. It wasn’t portrait mode but I know newer multi-camera phones can take the picture with both wide and normal angle cameras, and use stereo differences to estimate depth, maybe that’s the file?

Comment: Interesting. My `heif-convert` doesn't seem to have this option. Screenshot of version number and `heif-convert -h` : https://ibb.co/wpRjQL2

I believe it is the latest version, but I suppose I could be wrong.

Comment: Aside: It sounds like that photo was taken with HDR mode and this file is something to do with the HDR conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step-by-step How-To for extracting the depth map from iPhone portrait photos  (AuxiliaryImageType=disparity) using `heif-convert` on all platforms:

1. Make sure Docker is installed, e.g. [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/)
2. Open a terminal (e.g. Windows PowerShell) and use `cd` to navigate to the directory with your images.
3. Run this command to start an ubuntu container:

   `docker run -v ${PWD}:/mnt -it -w /mnt ubuntu`

   (For classic Windows command line (CMD), use `docker run -v %CD%:/mnt -it -w /mnt ubuntu` instead)

   Now you are inside the docker container and the directory should be your initially chosen location with your photos.
4. Run `apt-get update && apt-get install libheif-examples -y` to install the tool
5. Run `heif-convert -q 100 IMG_1234.heic IMG_1234.jpg`  (replace `IMG_1234` with your actual image file name)

   This should print out:

   ```
   File contains 1 images
   Written to IMG_1234.jpg
   Depth image written to IMG_1234-depth.jpg
   Auxiliary image written to IMG_1234-urn:com:apple:photo:2020:aux:semanticglassesmatte.jpg
   Auxiliary image written to IMG_1234-urn:com:apple:photo:2018:aux:portraiteffectsmatte.jpg
   Auxiliary image written to IMG_1234-urn:com:apple:photo:2020:aux:hdrgainmap.jpg
   Auxiliary image written to IMG_1234-urn:com:apple:photo:2019:aux:semanticskinmatte.jpg
   Auxiliary image written to IMG_1234-urn:com:apple:photo:2019:aux:semantichairmatte.jpg
   Auxiliary image written to IMG_1234-urn:com:apple:photo:2019:aux:semanticteethmatte.jpg
   ```