# How can I extract the non-blurred version of an iOS Portrait image from HEIC file? (i.e. turn "depth" off?)

Tags: iphone, heic

Following [How to extract depth map from .heif image created with iphone X using imagemagick](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105378/how-to-extract-depth-map-from-heif-image-created-with-iphone-x-using-imagemagic), I can extract the depth map as a byproduct of heif-convert. This produces an image with the blurred data and an image (half-size) of the depth map. The Apple Photos app has a feature to /disable/ the 3d blur, implying that either the blur is reversible (unlikely?), or the non-blur information is intact.

```
$ heif-convert IMG_0050.heic IMG_0050.jpg
File contains 1 images
Written to IMG_0050.jpg
Depth image written to IMG_0050-depth.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You Airdrop it to your Mac with options set to All Photos Data.
There will be a folder on your Mac for each image which contains the partially blurred image and the unblurred image (both contain also the depth information layers) as well as two AAE files.

Like so.

Video: https://vimeo.com/829910220

[image]
[image]
[image]